# $response->getBody()->getContents() returning empty string

Tags: php, response, psr-7

I have the code below:

```
<?php

use Zend\Diactoros\Response;

$response = new Response('This is the response content');

echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
echo $response->getBody();
```

I'm passing the body directly in the constructor.

I'm trying to get the body of this response, nothing more then it, but when i call the **getBody()** or the **getBody()->getContents()** it's give me a empty string.

I've tried another alternative that works:

```
<?php

use Zend\Diactoros\Response;

$response = new Response;

$response->getBody()->write('This is the response content');

echo $response->getBody()->getContents();
echo $response->getBody();
```

and it outputs:

> This is the response content This is the response content

Why the first and short form isn't working?

Comment: Why you don't using `Zend\Http\Response`?

Comment: 'Cause i'm not using **Zend Framework** at all, it's just **Zend Diactoros**, the Zend Framework PSR-7 implementation.

Comment: Ok. Your second solution is correct, but when you putting some strings to response body then it works like `echo`, so you don't need your `echo` on the end of file.

Comment: I found the problem, that's was my fault. Actually, the Response __constructor gets a StreamInterface as first parameter, not a string. The StreamInterface implementation is where you have to write your body. Other wise, you get no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, that's was my fault.

Actually, the Response __constructor gets a StreamInterface as first parameter, not a string.

The StreamInterface implementation is where you have to write your body, other wise, you get no response.

Here is the good approach:

```
$stream = new Stream('php://temp', 'rw');

$stream->write('This is a response');

$response = (new Response($stream));

echo $response->getBody();
```

Comment: `$response = new Response();`
`$response->getBody()->write("This is a response");`
`echo $response->getBody();`
It is the same.